# CKEditor right click select cut doesnt call the change event

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a CKEditor when i select some text then with mouse i right click -> select cut it does not trigger the change event, where as when i right click and then select paste it triggers the change event. What could be the solution for this?

I also noticed that the same thing happens in textarea as well. which is solved by (input) event. But (input)event does not work in CKEditor